# Max perimeter of triangle inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, derivatives, optimization

What is the maximum perimeter of a triangle inscibed in a circle of radius $1$?

I can't seem to find a proper equation to calculate the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use  [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) and [this](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/demonstrate-that-triangle-abc-sina-sinb-sinc-lt-3-180145)

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the maximum ought to be an equilateral triangle, with perimeter $3\sqrt 3$.

If you want to use calculus, let $\theta$ and $\phi$ be the *arcs* spanned by two of the sides, and calculate the perimeter as
$$ 2\sin \frac{\theta}2 + 2\sin\frac\phi2 + 2\sin\frac{2\pi-\theta-\phi}2 $$
Some manipulation of trigonometric identities will be involved.

Comment: Would that require calculating derivative of function of two variables? I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: @Josh: Yes, usually one would do it with partial derivatives. If you don't have those, you might be able to get through by first keeping $\theta$ constant and showing that the maximal perimeter for that $\theta$ occurs when $\phi=\frac{2\pi-\theta}{2}$ (i.e. an isosceles triangle). Then substitute that into the full formula and _now_ differentiate with respect to $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the triangle can be defined by two numbers $0 < \theta < \phi < 2 \pi$, where one vertex $A$ say is at (1,0) and vertices $B, C$ are at $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) \mbox{ and }  (\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$.

Use Pythagoras to calculate AB + BC + CA, and differentiate with respect to $\theta, \phi$ to get maximum.

Comment: Would that require calculating derivative of function of two variables? I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: You treat one variable as constant, and differentiate with respect to the other.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative